# Cannot read property 'styledComponentId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I use styled-component but couldn't find a way to find match element. I got error of

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'styledComponentId' of undefined`

This is my index.js
const Container = styled.h1`
  font-size: 14px;

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
const Container = styled.h1`
  font-size: 14px;
`

export default () => (<div>
    <Container>Hello</Container>
</div>)
export { Container }
```

This is my test (index.spec.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import IndexPage from './index'
import { Container } from './index'
import { enzymeFind } from 'styled-components/test-utils'

describe('Pages', () => {
  describe('Index page', () => {
    it('should have a container', function() {
      const wrapper = shallow(<IndexPage />)
      expect(enzymeFind(wrapper, Container).exists()).toBe(true)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.spec.js` you have:

```
import IndexPage from './index'
import { Container } from './index'
```

Yet the code you posted only has a default export in `index.js` - you might be mixing files you are importing from.

Comment: updated my code, I did export Container which is a styled component